# I am using a label as a button. How can I surround it with a border with round edges?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code that I am using with Xamarin Forms:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0,0,10,0">
   <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="faveIconLabel" Style="{StaticResource mediumIcon}" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" FontFamily="FontAwesome" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
   <Label Grid.Column="1" x:Name="hiddenIconLabel" Style="{StaticResource mediumIcon}" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" FontFamily="FontAwesome" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Can someone help and let me know how I can surround these two labels with a border to make them as much as possible look like buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frame can be used for this very purpose:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0,0,10,0">

    <Frame Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" OutlineColor="Black">
        <Label  x:Name="faveIconLabel" Style="{StaticResource mediumIcon}" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" FontFamily="FontAwesome" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </Frame>

    <Frame Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="5" OutlineColor="Black">
        <Label x:Name="hiddenIconLabel" Style="{StaticResource mediumIcon}" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" FontFamily="FontAwesome" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </Frame>

</Grid>
```